# writing ndb query to return the entity key along with the entity

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have an ndb User model:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    active = ndb.BooleanProperty(default=True,required=True)
    email= ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
```

that I call in order to retrieve a JSON file with all my users

```
@app.route('/get_users')
@login_required
def get_user_data():
    users = json.dumps([u.to_dict() for u in User.query().fetch()])
    return users
```

The output return looks like this:

```
[{"email": "user@email.com"},{"email": "user2@email.com"}....]
```

I would like to pass the ID of each user into the object so I can later on use it to query individual users. Ideally, I want to have an output that looks like this:

```
[{"email": "user@email.com", "id": xxxxxx},{"email": "user2@email.com", "id": xxxxxx}....]
```

I tried adding the following declaration into my model class:
  id = ndb.KeyProperty()

but I'm getting null values instead of retrieving the actual ID value from the datastore entities.

How do I go about pulling the keys of all users and adding them into the returned objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend `User.to_dict` to optionally include the key:

```
def to_dict(self, include=None, exclude=None, include_key=False):
    d = super().to_dict(include=include, exclude=exclude)
    if include_key:
        d['key'] = self.key.urlsafe().decode() # or some other JSON-friendly version of the key
    return d
```

Then change your code, like this:

```
users = json.dumps([u.to_dict(include_key=True) for u in User.query().fetch()])
```

The key can be reconstituted from its urlsafe key representation like this ([docs](https://googleapis.dev/python/python-ndb/latest/key.html#google.cloud.ndb.key.Key)):

```
>>> ndb.Key(urlsafe=b"agdleGFtcGxlcgsLEgRLaW5kGLkKDA")
Key('Kind', 1337, project='example')
```

Comment: does that mean I need to add the to_dict function on my User model? how do I change my "users = json.dumps([u.to_dict() for u in User.query().fetch()])" to reflect that?

Comment: Yes, you add the function to your model's code.  If you want the output to include the key, pass `to_dict(include_key=True)`.

Comment: this works :) a version of the key is returned:
"key": "ag1lc3NlbmNlLW9jdHJhchILEgVDaGVjaxiAgIDot9ONCgw"},

Not as it appears on datastore, but I guess this is needs to be decoded before I use it on queries to retrieve entities?

Comment: is it possible that 
        d['key'] = self.key.urlsafe().decode() # or some other JSON-friendly version of the key
had returned the keys in different order? The key from the json file attached to user 1 brings back user 2 when I query by key. The key from user 2 does not bring any user at all.

Comment: That's unlikely, since `self` refers to an individual `User` instance.  If you can reliably reproduce that behaviour, it might be best to produce an [mre] and ask another question - I don't think it will be solvable in the comments here.